# Pygame blitting only updated surfaces

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

Right now I have an x by y array to hold integers that decide which tile to draw to the screen. (The integers choose which tile in my `tile_arr` to blit)

For better performance, I only want the ints that changed to be blit'ed again.

**EXAMPLE 1:**

For example right now I have something like:

```
tile_arr = [image1,image2,image3,image4]
arr = [[2,2,2],[2,2,2],[2,2,2]]
```

Then depending on what the user does, some values in `arr` might change, so lets say:

```
arr[0][0]=1
arr[2][1]=1
```

Which would give us the array:

```
arr=[[1,2,2],[2,2,2],[2,1,2]]
```

now when blitting to the screen, I would blit images from the `tile_arr`: image numbers 1,2,2 to the top row, 2,2,2, to the middle row, and 2,1,2 to the bottom row.  When I blit the array, I use a `screen.blit` for each value or arr, that's nine blits.  I would rather only do two blits. (Use `screen.blit` only twice)

**EXAMPLE 2:**

```
tile_arr = [green.bmp, red.bemp, blue.bmp]
feild_arr = [[0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0]]
```

Output:

> G  G  G
>
> G  G  G
>
> G  G  G

User changes `feild_arr` to `[[1,0,1], [0,2,0], [0,1,2]]`

Output:

> R  G  R
>
> G  B  G
>
> G  R  B

Now I only want to call `sceen.blit()` 5 times, leaving the 4 Green sqaures green, because nothing changed.

I thought of making another array, which would be just a copy of the first.  Then run through it and compare to the new array to see what changed, but I think there is a better and faster way to this.  Now the example is only 3x3 so making a duplicate array isn't too bad, but I'm working with a lot bigger arrays, and when you're blitting a 30x20 array, I need all the shortcuts I can get.

**How do I only blit when the interger values in an array have been changed, and skip (don't blit) the values that have not changed?**

Comment: I don't know if I exactly understand. But have you tried any sprite groups? [1] Maybe `RenderUpdates` http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.RenderUpdates. [2] Using so many arrays, `numpy` could be useful to you.

Comment: thanks, I'll look around this `RenderUpdates` and see if I find what I'm looking for, it looks like it is what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use screen.blit only once, calling with a list of the rectangles that changed.

I think the best aproach is to create you own class deriving from DirtySprite:

`class Cell: pygame.sprite.DirtySprite`

which already has attributes for holding an image and a rectangle and you can add an attributes to hold the number and a method to change de number that will set it as dirty.

Then you can use [LayeredDirty](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.LayeredDirty) class to render the dirty sprites on the screen.